# построчное вычитание из pandas dataframe элементов списка

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите пожалуйста

есть список

```
x = [0.454453, 0.563333, 0.879905, 0.769977, 0.123533, 0.986533]
```

есть

```
dataframe = [[0.754553, 0.563333, 0.899055, 0.769877, 0.123232, 0.785633]
             [0.954553, 0.863333, 0.399055, 0.669877, 0.723232, 0.185633]
             [0.854553, 0.463333, 0.699055, 0.969877, 0.223232, 0.385633]]
```

как из dataframe вычесть элементы списка x построчно, т.е.

```
0.754553 - 0.454453
0.563333 - 0.454453 и т.д
```

соответственно дальше:

```
0.954553 - 0.563333
0.863333 - 0.563333
```

из нулевой строки вычитаем всегда нулевой элемент из списка x
из первой строки вычитаем всегда первый элемент из списка x

результат необходим в таком же порядке и записан в матрице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-тов голову не приходит векторизованное решение. Как-нибудь так можно:

```
res = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    for j in x:
        res.append([i[k]-j for k in range(1,len(i))])
```

ну и в res будет список списков с результатом.

```
[[0.30010000000000003, 0.10887999999999998, 0.44460200000000005, 0.31542400000000004, -0.331221, 0.33118000000000003], [0.19122000000000006, 0.0, 0.3357220000000001, 0.20654400000000006, -0.44010099999999996, 0.22230000000000005], [-0.12535200000000002, -0.3165720000000001, 0.01915, -0.11002800000000001, -0.756673, -0.09427200000000002], [-0.015423999999999993, -0.20664400000000005, 0.12907800000000003, -9.999999999998899e-05, -0.646745, 0.015656000000000003], [0.63102, 0.43979999999999997, 0.775522, 0.646344, -0.0003010000000000096, 0.6621], [-0.23197999999999996, -0.4232, -0.08747799999999994, -0.21665599999999996, -0.863301, -0.20089999999999997], [0.5001, 0.40888, -0.055398, 0.21542399999999995, 0.268779, -0.26882], [0.39122, 0.30000000000000004, -0.16427799999999998, 0.10654399999999997, 0.159899, -0.3777], [0.07464799999999994, -0.01657200000000003, -0.48085000000000006, -0.2100280000000001, -0.15667300000000006, -0.694272], [0.18457599999999996, 0.093356, -0.37092200000000003, -0.10010000000000008, -0.046745000000000037, -0.584344], [0.83102, 0.7398, 0.275522, 0.5463439999999999, 0.599699, 0.06209999999999999], [-0.03198000000000001, -0.12319999999999998, -0.587478, -0.31665600000000005, -0.263301, -0.8009], [0.4001, 0.008879999999999999, 0.24460199999999999, 0.515424, -0.23122099999999998, -0.06881999999999999], [0.29122000000000003, -0.09999999999999998, 0.135722, 0.406544, -0.340101, -0.17769999999999997], [-0.02535200000000004, -0.41657200000000005, -0.18085000000000007, 0.08997199999999994, -0.6566730000000001, -0.49427200000000004], [0.08457599999999998, -0.306644, -0.07092200000000004, 0.19989999999999997, -0.546745, -0.384344], [0.73102, 0.3398, 0.575522, 0.846344, 0.09969900000000001, 0.2621], [-0.13198, -0.5232, -0.287478, -0.016656000000000004, -0.763301, -0.6009]]​
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Как вы поняли, что нужно из каждой строки списка dataframe последовательно вычитать каждое значение из списка х? В условиях об этом вроде ничего не сказано. Я понял так, что нужно брать значения только с соответствующими индексами (из строки i вычитать элемент i).

Comment: @SergFSM из примеров, приведенных автором вопроса.